# Could not change Nutch http proxy scheme to basic

Tags: proxy, nutch

No matter what I typed, it always goes to NTLM. I want my scheme as basic.
With my proxy, id and pwd, curl works.
However Nutch does not work.
I think it could be the matter of encoding(capital letter, etc.), so want to figure it out.
However, as it always sets scheme as NTLM, it hides id and pwd in log.

```
---httpclient-auth.xml---
<auth-configuration>
        <credentials username="id" password="pw">
                <default/>
        </credentials>
</auth-configuration>

---nutch-site.xml---
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>http.agent.name</name>
        <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>http.robots.agents</name>
        <value>My Nutch Spider,*</value>
    </property>

        <property>
                <name>plugin.includes</name>
                <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
        </property>

    <property>
        <name>http.proxy.host</name>
        <value>proxyhost</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>http.proxy.port</name>
        <value>9000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>http.proxy.username</name>
        <value>id</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>http.proxy.password</name>
        <value>pw</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

---hadoop.log---
INFO  httpclient.Http - http.proxy.host = proxyhost
INFO  httpclient.Http - http.proxy.port = 9000
INFO  httpclient.Http - http.timeout = 10000
INFO  httpclient.Http - http.content.limit = 65536
INFO  httpclient.Http - http.agent = My Nutch Spider/Nutch-1.4
INFO  httpclient.Http - http.accept.language = en-us,en-    gb,en;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
INFO  auth.AuthChallengeProcessor - ntlm authentication scheme     selected
INFO  httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Failure authenticating     with NTLM <any realm>@proxyhost:9000
INFO  auth.AuthChallengeProcessor - ntlm authentication scheme     selected
INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - -activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0,     fetchQueues.totalSize=0
INFO  httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Failure authenticating     with NTLM <any realm>@proxyhost:9000
INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - fetch of http://url/ failed     with: Http code=407, url=http://url/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not selected the proper scheme while configuring the httpclient-auth.xml file.

Here is the configuration that I have used and is working perfectly fine for me.

```
<auth-configuration>
        <credentials username="<username>" password="<password>">
                 <authscope host="<hostname>" port="80" scheme="basic" realm="<realm_value>"/>
        </credentials>
</auth-configuration>
```

Let me know how it goes at your end after trying this solution...